# Can't install cabal-doctest-1, getting compilation error

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I tried to install cabal-doctest-1, but I got a compilation error like this:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring cabal-doctest-1.0.1...
Building cabal-doctest-1.0.1...
Failed to install cabal-doctest-1.0.1
Build log ( C:\Users\Podlovics Péter\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\cabal-doctest-1.0.1.log ):
Building cabal-doctest-1.0.1...
Preprocessing library cabal-doctest-1.0.1...
[1 of 1] Compiling Distribution.Extra.Doctest ( src\Distribution\Extra\Doctest.hs, dist\build\Distribution\Extra\Doctest.o )

src\Distribution\Extra\Doctest.hs:174:70: error:
    * Could not deduce (Data.String.IsString
                          Distribution.Types.UnqualComponentName.UnqualComponentName)
        arising from a use of `fromString'
      from the context: GHC.Stack.Types.HasCallStack
        bound by a type expected by the context:
                   GHC.Stack.Types.HasCallStack =>
                   Library -> ComponentLocalBuildInfo -> IO ()
        at src\Distribution\Extra\Doctest.hs:(147,3)-(197,9)
      or from: GHC.Stack.Types.HasCallStack
        bound by a type expected by the context:
                   GHC.Stack.Types.HasCallStack =>
                   TestSuite -> ComponentLocalBuildInfo -> IO ()
        at src\Distribution\Extra\Doctest.hs:(174,5)-(197,9)
    * In the second argument of `(==)', namely
        `fromString testSuiteName'
      In the first argument of `when', namely
        `(testName suite == fromString testSuiteName)'
      In the expression:
        when (testName suite == fromString testSuiteName)
cabal: Leaving directory '.'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cabal-doctest-1.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I tried hard-coding FlexibleContexts into the .hs file, but it didn't help. I have Cabal 1.24.

EDIT:

I updated to GHC 8.0.2, installed cabal-doctest-1, but the lnker doesn't seem to find it. Also I can't import DocTest into any module (you can find the searched locations below). Here's the linker error:

```
C:\cabal\cabal-master>cabal install distributive-0.5.2
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring distributive-0.5.2...
Failed to install distributive-0.5.2
Build log ( C:\Users\Podlovics Péter\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\distributive-0.5.2.log ):
cabal: Entering directory 'C:\Users\PODLOV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-13372\distributive-0.5.2'
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\PODLOV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-13372\distributive-0.5.2'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
distributive-0.5.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
user error ('C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.0.2\bin\ghc.exe' exited with
an error:
C:/Program Files/Haskell Platform/8.0.2/mingw/bin/ld.exe: cannot find
-lHScabal-doctest-1-3OH6xMXYfakDTTZ99VQuTb
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
)
```

and here's the location list:

```
Failed to load interface for `DocTest'
Locations searched:
  DocTest.hs
  DocTest.lhs
  DocTest.hsig
  DocTest.lhsig
```

Thanks in advance